# "Found nothing" error with JSONPath filter and gatling

Tags: json, jsonpath, gatling

I'm trying to filter this JSON by green vegetables :

```
[
    {
        "vegetable": {
            "name": "peas",
            "color": "green"
        },
        "meet": {
            "name":"beef",
            "color":"red"
        }
    },
    {
        "vegetable": {
            "name": "potato",
            "color": "yellow"
        },
        "meet": {
            "name":"lamb",
            "color":"brown"
        }
    }
]
```

with a JSONPath with gatling like

```
val searchGreenVegetable = exec(http("Search green vegetable")
                                  .get("http://myUrl/json/")
                                  .check(jsonPath("""$..vegetable[?(@.color=="green")]""").exists)
                           )
```

but I always have the "found nothing" error in the gatling report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is correct, this was indeed a [bug](https://github.com/gatling/jsonpath/issues/10).
It's fixed in 0.6.3 that was just released.

Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val searchGreenVegetable = exec(http("Search green vegetable")
                                  .get("http://myUrl/json/")
                                  .check(jsonPath("$..vegetable[?(@.color=='green')]").exists)
                           )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! But it doesn't work, I still have the same error.

Comment: @kalle Gatling doesn't use your implementation but our own.